# How to use regular expressions with Hibernate/Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, hibernate, seam

I'm trying to implement a web service which accepts a list of strings, each of which is a regular expression.  These need to be compared against six columns of a database, and any rows which match need to be returned.

I believe Oracle has a regexp_like() function which I might be able to use, but I'm looking for the *best* way to do this using Hibernate, so I'm not working against the persistence engine.

I started with something like this, in which the participants collection contains the regular expressions:

```
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
List<Message> m1 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
    .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class).add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.in("Node2Id", participants),
            Restrictions.in("Node2Id", participants))).list();
List<Message> m2 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
    .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class).add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.in("Node3Id", participants),
            Restrictions.in("Node4Id", participants))).list();
List<Message> m3 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
    .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class).add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.in("Node5Id", participants),
            Restrictions.in("Node6Id", participants))).list();
messages.addAll(m1);
messages.addAll(m2);
messages.addAll(m3);
```

This doesn't work because "in" won't do what I want, and this does not appear to tell Hibernate to use a regular expression match.

This is the only answer I've come up with, but it looks really ugly:

```
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
for (String re : participants) {
    List<Message> m1 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
        .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class)
        .add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_1, " + re + ")"),
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_2, " + re + ")")
        )).list();
    List<Message> m2 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
        .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class)
        .add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_3, " + re + ")"),
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_4, " + re + ")")
        )).list();
    List<Message> m3 = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate())
        .createCriteria(MessageSSR.class)
        .add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_5, " + re + ")"),
                Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like(NODE_6, " + re + ")")
        )).list();
    messages.addAll(m1);
    messages.addAll(m2);
    messages.addAll(m3);
}
```

I'm trying to push as much of this over to Oracle as I can.  This appraoch seems likely to work, but putting the restrictions in without using parameters means I'm losing a lot of potential efficiency.  Can anyone see a better way to do this?  For simplicity, I'm trusting the regular expressions that are being passed to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing in the hibernate docs for performing regular expression queries (using HQL or Criteria queries). The approach using the `sqlRestrictions` should probably be changed to one of the overloaded methods to avoid a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Example code:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like({alias}.NODE_1, ?)", re, Hibernate.STRING)
```

Comment: Works great if you need to use the :alpha: operator Oracle provides since overriding the : with \\: never seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Similar working example

```
 Criterion criterion = Restrictions.sqlRestriction("regexp_like (column_name, ?, 'i')", "(^|\\s)"+searchValue+"($|\\s|.$)", StringType.INSTANCE);
```